# Find out which files a process is writing to

Tags: firefox, cpu, process, cpu-usage, io

I have this very annoying problem with Firefox for months where its CPU usage jumps to over 24% after a while when idle. Any official troubleshooting has lead to no positive results (tried to reset, fresh install, no addons, etc.) and yet I see it doing insane I/O writes when that is happening. I know this might not correlate to actually writing to the disk, but without any means to check it directly I am now looking for a way to find it out myself.

How can I find out which files the process is writing to? My goal is to understand whether it is actually writing to files or not and which files are they, because that might lead to a clue of the problem. If it is writing to files then I can see which files they are, if not then I'll explore what that means.

Is there any way to find out which files a process is writing to?

I searched for other questions about this, but the closest ones only mention finding the I/O data of a process, not specifically finding which files it is writing to.

EDIT: This is on Windows 10

I already tried `ProcMon` and `Process Hacker` but they only show I/O rates, none appear to provide a way to tell which files a process is writing to.

Comment: I second Process Monitor but you could also use the built in resmon to get some idea. Disk - Disk Activity

Comment: I already tried `ProcMon` but I could not find a way to check which files a process is writing to, only the data transfer rates like `Process Hacker`

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using Process Explorer rather than Process Monitor

Comment: I have the installer still open in front of me `Procmon64.exe`

Comment: That should be fine, I would create a filter for Process Name is FireFox.exe and Operation is WriteFile

Comment: That said, if you have CPU issue, I would be tempted to run in an admin prompt `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` when you next get the issue. Leave it running for 1 minute then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`. Then open gp.etl in Windows Performance Analyzer (which you can get from the store or by downloading the SDK) That will help to show you what is going on.

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you are suggesting, this tool is quite complex to work with for someone that is using it for the first time based on basic instructions found on the web for low level debugging

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, the usual choice is [SysInternals ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

On Linux, `fatrace` will report all writes system-wide, while `strace --decode-fd -p <pid>` will show writes done by the specified processes. There are also other tools (inotifywait, perf trace).

Comment: I have added the platform to the question, it is windows yes. I had already tried `ProcMon` but I did not see any way to check which files it is writing to, only shows data transfer information like `Process Hacker`

Comment: That sounds very much like you were using ProcExp, not ProcMon. They're both SysInternals tools, but don't confuse the two.

Comment: I already replied to the comments of the other user that I have the `Procmon64.exe` still open in front of me.

Comment: Well, that's quite odd. ProcMon doesn't _have_ I/O statistics like Process Hacker or ProcExp – its entire window is literally nothing else but a list of operations, each with a column for the process name and the corresponding file name. (Or registry path.) It should look like this: https://i.imgur.com/G9sgWZI.png